# Consigo rodar um app Reactive Native no Iphone pelo Windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, react-native, iphone

Bom, eu tenho um Iphone Xr e quero desenvolver um app em Reactive Native e testar ele usando meu Iphone(Por USB, sem necessidade de emuladores), mas o meu computador é um windows 10, e não um mac. Mesmo não sendo um mac, eu usando Reactive e o USB do Iphone, consigo rodar?

Ou seria necessário um emulador de Iphone ou Android?

Answer (score 2):

Olá, é possível sim, acesse: https://expo.io/ , siga as instruções e você vai conseguir ver seu app em seu iphone rodando dentro do app da expo que você também deverá baixar no seu iphone.
Aqui: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/get-started/installation/?redirected você tem um tutorial explicando melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Para rodar o comando `react-native run-ios` é necessário a ferramenta Xcode que só funciona no OSX.

Hoje em dia já tem soluções(gambiarras), porém, não são muito bem vistas, pois são lentas.

Está sendo muito usada por usuários windows é o Expo. Com o Expo é possível criar aplicativos para iOS e Android em sua máquina Windows / Linux sem ter o Xcode ou o Android Studio instalado.

---

Referência: [Expo](https://expo.io/)